# How to run 'sudo' command in windows

Tags: windows

How would I run the following command in windows:

```
$ sudo django-admin.py startproject NEW
```

?

Comment: It is better to avoid using terminal commands in Windows. Instead, try doing the same with the help of an IDE, like Eclipse+PyDev. It will make things much simpler.

Comment: @Pushpak Dagade:  I was off-put by your comment, in general, but when I went to go type this I realized this is STACK OVERFLOW. These are the people that DO use the terminal in Windows. =) I mean, PowerShell likely wouldn't exist otherwise.

Comment: Also, what if he were creating a script to automate a task? (Yes, I realize you could run THAT as priviledged user.)

Comment: Try my [wsudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642324/1768303), a sudo-like tool for Windows available as a Chocolatey package.

Comment: I know this question is very old. But actually now there is answer for it. Check out Windows 10 WSL: https://winaero.com/enable-wsl-windows-10-fall-creators-update/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70187902/14680048

Comment: Microsoft just added "Sudo for Windows." 
See https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/sudo/
The [run as](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command will continue to be supported and enables running programs as other users, including but not limited to as administrator, which Sudo for Windows does not yet support.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

There is no `sudo` command in Windows.  The nearest equivalent is "run as administrator."

You can do this using the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) command with an administrator trust-level, or by right-clicking the program in the UI and choosing *"run as administrator."*

Comment: Do you know if the behavior of runas varies from version to version? I have installed Win7 enterprise and all combinations I have tried with runas creates  the new cmd without admin privileges

Comment: Sudo for Windows (sudowin) allows authorized users to launch processes with elevated privileges using their own passphrase. Unlike the runas command, Sudo for Windows preserves the user's profile and ownership of created objects.  You can get it here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/

Comment: runas is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing. This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: there is now baby! https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-sudo-for-windows/

Answer (score 138):

All the answers explain how to elevate your command in a new console host. So, I wrote: **gsudo** to behave like `Unix/Linux sudo`, allowing to execute the command inside the **current** console.

### gsudo

- Source Code, Documentation, and Releases available at: https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo

#### Most relevant features:

- Elevates in the current console (no new window)
- Elevates `cmd` commands, but also PowerShell / WSL / Git-Bash / cygwin / Msys / commands natively.
- Optional: Credentials Cache (Elevate many times with only one UAC popup)

#### Installation

- Using [scoop](https://scoop.sh/): `scoop install gsudo`
- Using Chocolatey: `choco install gsudo`
- Using Winget: `winget install gerardog.gsudo`
- Manually: Download the latest release, unzip, and add to path, from https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo/releases/

### Demo

[image: gsudo demo]

Comment: You can also install it from `winget` with `winget install gsudo`

Comment: I still get the error ```bash: gsudo: command not found```

Comment: @LibinThomas: Make sure you are running the latest version (v1.3.0), that you restarted your consoles (to refresh the `PATH`). If still fails, please [create a GitHub Issue](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo/issues), describing how did you installed gsudo? which bash are you using? what you get when you run `which gsudo` and `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 30):

Open notepad and paste this code:

```sh
@echo off
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c cd /d %CD% && %*'"
@echo on
```

Then, save the file as `sudo.cmd`. Copy this file and paste it at `C:\Windows\System32` or add the path where `sudo.cmd` is to your PATH Environment Variable.

When you open command prompt, you can now run something like `sudo start .`.

If you want the admin command prompt window to stay open when you run the command, change the code in notepad to this:

```sh
@echo off
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/k cd /d %CD% && %*'"
@echo on
```

Explanation:

`powershell -Command` runs a powershell command.

`Start-Process` is a powershell command that starts a process, in this case, command prompt.

`-Verb RunAs` runs the command as admin.

`-Argument-List` runs the command with arguments.

Our arguments are `'/c cd /d %CD% && %*'`. `%*` means all arguments, so if you did `sudo foo bar`, it would run in command prompt `foo bar` because the parameters are foo and bar, and `%*` returns `foo bar`. `cd /d %CD%` is a command to go to the current directory. This will ensure that when you open the elevated window, the directory will be the same as the normal window. the `&&` means that if the first command is successful, run the second command.

The `/c` is a cmd parameter for closing the window after the command is finished, and the `/k` is a cmd parameter for keeping the window open.

Credit to [Adam Plocher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/730566/adam-plocher) for the staying in the current directory code.

Comment: One problem with that is that once elevated, you're no longer in what was the current folder, but rather in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Comment: @noseratio true, it appears that changing it to this will do the trick, however: `powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/k cd /d %CD% && %*'"`

Comment: @AdamPlocher, that might work but could have issues if the command line `%*` has quotes. That's why I created [`wsudo`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54642324/1768303), PowerShell-based.

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Comment: Can you not just skip the `echo` lines one and three by prepending `@` to the powershell line?

Answer (score 13):

I've created `wsudo`, an open-source `sudo`-like CLI tool for Windows to run programs or commands with elevated right, **in the context of the current directory**. It's available as a [Chocolatey package](https://chocolatey.org/packages/wsudo).

I use it a lot for stuff like configuring build agents, admin things like `sfc /scannow`, `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` or simply for installing/updating my local Chocolatey packages. Use at your own risk.

## Installation

```
choco install wsudo
```

[Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) must be already installed.

## Purpose

`wsudo` is a Linux `sudo`-like tool for Windows to invoke a program with elevated rights (as Administrator) from a non-admin shell command prompt and keeping its current directory.

This implementation doesn't depend on the legacy Windows Script Host (`CScript`). Instead, it uses a helper PowerShell 5.1 script that invokes `"Start-Process -Wait -Verb runAs ..."` cmdlet. Your system most likely already has PowerShell 5.x installed, otherwise you'll be offered to install it as a dependency.

## Usage

`wsudo` runs a program or an inline command with elevated rights in the current directory. Examples:

```
wsudo .\myAdminScript.bat 
wsudox "del C:\Windows\Temp\*.* && pause"
wasudo cup all -y
wasudox start notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

**For more details, visit the [GitHub repro](https://github.com/noseratio/choco/tree/master/wsudo).**

Comment: Thank you for publishing "wsudo", it's quite useful for me. I think your wsudo's advantage is **keeping working directory** not like the alternatives.  I couldn't find one 
 can keep CWD other than wsudo. I think you should emphasize this point in the description. I really appreciate your work.

Comment: One more thing to let you know. Do you know [address bar hack](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+address+bar+hack+open+cmd) to open shell directly ?  I usually use this hack, but I was very frustrated when I want to get elevated shell with this hack. I tried to find many alternatives but not works. I finally can open one with "wasudo [shell]". I love to have this. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @benok, I do, it's a handy hack indeed! Glad `wasudo` made it easier for you. I myself mostly live in the VSCode integrated console terminal, so I just type `wasudo` there :) The next improvement would be to inherit the [environment vars](https://github.com/noseratio/choco/issues/2).

Comment: I think in this case I actually prefer gsudo (from Gerardo Grignoli's answer above). This one seems to kick you into a powershell prompt where-as gsudo will actually run it within the same window, making it closer to an actual *nix sudo.

Comment: @Sollace, pretty sure gsudo is great, although giving it's tunneling nature, does it work with interactive console apps like FAR Manager or Midnight Commander?

Comment: @noseratio Good question... Let's find out! I couldn't find a version of Midnight Commander for Window, so I installed Far using `sudo choco install far` , then ran far normally to just see what it does. Then I ran it again using `sudo far`, and... Yeah. It works perfectly.

I'm able to navigate around, open files, and even click menu items with the mouse. It acts exactly like you would expect if you ran far on its own, which honestly makes a lot of sense. It is just a two-way pipe. :)

Comment: @Sollace awesome, Gerardo has done a great job!

Answer (score 7):

`runas` command requires the users to type password.
If you don't want to type password and want to just click the UAC dialog, use `Start-Process -Verb runas` in PowerShell instead of `runas` command.

see: http://satob.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/06/17/013217

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Answer (score 7):

There kind of is. I created Sudo for Windows back in 2007? 08? Here's the security paper I wrote about it - https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/bestprac/sudo-windows-sudowin-1726. Pretty sure http://sudowin.sf.net still works too.

Answer (score 5):

You normally wouldn't, since you wouldn't run it under *nix regardless. Do development in a user directory, and deploy afterwards to system directories.

Answer (score 5):

in Windows, you can use the runas command.
For linux users, there are some alternatives for sudo in windows, you can check this out

http://helpdeskgeek.com/free-tools-review/5-windows-alternatives-linux-sudo-command/

Answer (score 4):

You could use runas command - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx
or sudowin - http://sourceforge.net/projects/sudowin/

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Answer (score 4):

To just run a command as admin in a non-elevated Powershell, you can use `Start-Process` directly, with the right options, particularly `-Verb runas`.

It's a lot more convoluted than `sudo`, particularly because you can't just re-use the previous command with an additional option. You need to specify the arguments to your command separately.

Here is an example, using the route command to change the gateway :

This fails because we are not in an elevated PS:

```
> route change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.3
The requested operation requires elevation.
```

This works after accepting the UAC:

```
> Start-Process route -ArgumentList "change 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.3" -Verb runas
```

Or for a command that requires `cmd.exe`:

```
> Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList "/c other_command arguments ..." -Verb runas
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no sudo command in case of windows and also there is no need to put any $. For installing Angular CLI through node.js command prompt in windows, I just wrote **npm install -g @angular/cli** and then pressed Enter. It worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The following vbs script allows to launch a given command with arguments with elevation and mimics the behavior of the original unix sudo command for a limited set of used cases (it will not cache credentials nor it allows to truly execute commands with different credentials). I put it on `C:\Windows\System32`.

```vb
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
exe = objArgs(0)
args = ""
IF objArgs.Count >= 2 Then
   args = args & objArgs(1)
End If
For it = 2 to objArgs.Count - 1
   args = args & " " & objArgs(it)
Next
Set objShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell")
windir=objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WINDIR%")
Set objShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShellApp.ShellExecute exe, args, "", "runas", 1
set objShellApp = nothing
```

Example use on a command prompt `sudo net start service`

Comment: how can we make the script wait for user input, so we can read the output of the shell program?

Comment: You mean interactive shell command? Well, you should first try to make sure the command launched will be waited for return. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951837/wait-for-shell-command-to-complete) it seems it's possible. Then you should get the output from the shell objects and output it, which I guess it's also possible. Don't expect everything you can do in unix will be possible, though.

Comment: On windows 10 it throws a syntax error on line 1 char 6.

Comment: This is elevation of a user account in Administrators; sudo is another thing.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Powershell you can use Start-Process command with option `-Verb RunAs` to start and elevated process.
Here is my sudo function example:

```
function sudo {
    Start-Process @args -verb runas
}
```

Ex: Open hosts file as Admin in notepad

```
sudo notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I tried steps below after doing some research & succeeded

1.Install scoop using powershell 3 (iex (new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('https://get.scoop.sh'))
2. do scoop install --global sudo
3. make sure paths (C:\Users\\scoop\shims & C:\ProgramData\scoop\shims) added in environmental path variable.

Answer (score 1):

open the console as a administrator. Right Click on the command prompt or bash -> more and select "run as administrator"

Answer (score 0):

Using the `sudo` command for window users gives you the following suggestions:

First, install the `scoop` package management tool and execute the following commands:

[image]

Then use `scoop` to install the `sudo` command:

[image]

Finally, you can execute the command with `sudo`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am glad to help you.

To make a sudo command follow the steps :-

1. Make a folder env in C:\ Drive.
2. Make a folder inside the env folder named as bin.
3. Now add C:\env\bin to your PATH.
4. Create a file sudo.bat in C:\env\bin.
5. Edit it with notepad and write this code :-
   https://gist.github.com/coder-examples/5ca6c141d6d356ddba4e356d63fb2c13

Hope this will help you

Comment: This answer should include the text of the batch file, not depend on a link off site because of link rot. Also the answer should include the disclaimer that this script seeks to emulate the coarse behavior of sudo, but isn't really sudo (it's a pseudo-sudo).