# How to open an elevated cmd using command line for Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd, command

How do I open a elevated command prompt using command lines on a normal cmd?

For example, I use `runas /username:admin cmd` but the cmd that was opened does not seem to be elevated! Any solutions?

Comment: I tried all the answers.Most useful answer without any softwares and least no of actions is https://stackoverflow.com/a/40942828/9217577

Answer (score 222):

I ran into the same problem and the only way I was able to open the CMD as administrator from CMD was doing the following:

1. Open CMD
2. Write `powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. A pop-up window will appear asking to open a CMD as administrator

Comment: Good answer. I added and edit I used to make it run in one command line!

Comment: I created a batch file with this and saved it as admincmd.bat in my windows folder so all I have to do is type "admincmd" hit enter and it opens an admin cmd.(I also added another line to the batch file with "exit" so it closes the non admin cmd window)

Comment: Why not place the cmd (and any parameters) on the end. Having the command is odd from a readability standpoint.

Comment: Needed this to elevate a prompt running as another user.

Comment: is there any way to avoid the following pop-up? I want to spawn an elevated cmd from a non interactive script.

Comment: @31bit You mean the UAC pop-up? You would have to disable UAC I think (unless there's some loophole I'm not aware of), though for security reasons I STRONGLY urge you to leave UAC enabled.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering what "-Verb RunAs" means: It has nothing to do with powershell or cmd. It's an inherent parameter of the Start-Process command which refers to the win API function `ShellExecuteExW`. This function has a struct parameter `SHELLEXECUTEINFOA` which has a `lpVerb` (string) member that specifies the action to be performed. There are other verbs that can be used. So the runas verb is actually a parameter of the win API which launches an application as Administrator.

Comment: The documentation links to MS were too long for the above comment ^^
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shellexecuteinfoa
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexw

Answer (score 55):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to the top answer, but with the power of aliases you can get away with just typing the following:

```
powershell "start cmd -Verb runAs"
```

This is just a shorter version of user3018703 excellent
solution:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs"
```

Comment: Note that `-v` is no longer a shortcut for `-Verb`, as there is ambiguity between -Verb and -Verbose, so one needs to explicitly spell out `-Verb`

Comment: If you need to pass arguments to cmd, such as running a one off task, pass the arguments as an escaped string:
`powershell "start \"cmd\" \"/C echo \\"hi && pause\\"\" -v runAs"`

Answer (score 50):

## Simple way I did after trying other answers here

#### Method 1: WITHOUT a 3rd party program (I used this)

1. Create a file called `sudo.bat` (you can replace `sudo` with any name you want) with following content

   `powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd \"/k cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs"`
2. Move `sudo.bat` to a folder in your `PATH`; if you don't know what that means, just move these files to `c:\windows\`
3. Now `sudo` will work in Run dialog (<kbd>win+r</kbd>) or in explorer address bar (this is the best part :))

#### Method 2: WITH a 3rd party program

1. Download [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) and unzip it.
2. Create a file called `sudo.bat` (you can replace `sudo` with any name you want) with following content

   `nircmdc elevate cmd /k "cd /d %cd%"`
3. Move `nircmdc.exe` and `sudo.bat` to a folder in your `PATH`; if you don't know what that means, just move these files to `c:\windows\`
4. Now `sudo` will work in Run dialog (<kbd>win+r</kbd>) or in explorer address bar (this is the best part :))

Comment: While both solutions work, unfortunately they will result in the **UAC** dialog showing up on top (z-order-wise) but **not** getting **focused**. (Tested on Win10x64 v1607 build14393.447.)

Comment: @Ogmios that's rather odd. does the dialog work properly when not initiated like this? I've been very happily using this without such issues. Maybe it's because of some other configuration that you've changed?

Comment: Yes, the UAC dialog works as expected in all other situations (I've encountered). This is the only exception. And of course I have changed my system in other ways, but I haven't found anything that might have a hidden effect on this dialog.

Comment: @Ogmios sorry then mate, I can't think of anything else you can do to fix this. You should probably try the other solutions to see if they are  better for you. Cheers

Comment: While powershell isn't a third party, it is not a stock program, and you're sort of writing a third party program to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @undrline what do you mean it's not stock? Powershell is installed in all windows systems AFAIK. Am I mistaken? Also, anything you want done is a custom program you've to write. That's first party not third-party 

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar via MS docs "PowerShell comes installed by default in every Windows, starting with Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1."  The question doesn't apply to a specific version of Windows and was asked in 2013, when it would've been highly likely to have been Windows XP.

Comment: I rolled this up into an installable solution: https://webinstall.dev/sudo/

Comment: @coolaj86 awesome. Please do credit me with a link back if my answer helped you even partially

Comment: Please don't use random executables from the web that 'help you elevate privileges'. Bad, bad practice.

Comment: @Xalorous in general you're right, but nircmd is from a well known and popular company. You can likely verify hashes of the files you download.

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Cause it somehow opens CMD and cd's into the directory where I ran the .bat file, this is cool. Does "%cd%" part do that?

Comment: @Tims This tells powershell to open, and -Command makes it run "Start-Process cmd \"/k cd /d %cd%\" -Verb RunAs" on the first line of the session. This in turn launches an elevated cmd.exe, and /k makes cmd.exe run "cd /d %cd%" on the first line of the session. At some point along the way (I think during the powershell part of the operation), %cd% gets expanded to the working directory you started in, so you don't have to navigate back to it. I'm not sure how robust this is, but it works, somehow.

Answer (score 40):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385791.aspx), the Windows security model...

> does not grant administrative privileges at all
>   times. **Even administrators run under standard privileges** when they
>   perform non-administrative tasks that do not require elevated
>   privileges.

You have the *Create this task with administrative privileges* option in the *Create new task* dialog (*Task Manager > File > Run new task*), but there is no built-in way to effectively elevate privileges using the command line.

However, there are some third party tools (internally relying on Windows APIs) you can use to elevate privileges from the command line:

#### [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html):

1. Download it and unzip it.
2. `nircmdc elevate cmd`

#### [windosu](https://www.npmjs.org/package/windosu):

1. Install it: `npm install -g windosu` (requires [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed)
2. `sudo cmd`

Comment: Thank you, `nircmdc elevate  route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0..0.0 192.168.1.1` finally worked. The other `runas /user:...` ways prompted for a password despite already being an admin (killed batch mode).

Comment: Thanks for `nircmdc elevate cmd`

Comment: After intalling `nircmd`, to have it work like Linux `sudo`, create a `sudo.bat` file in your path with this content:  `nircmd elevate %*`. Then you can do, for example, `sudo net stop W3SVC`

Comment: i think windosu is by far the simplest and most elegant way of doing this, especially if you are a dev... thanks man. I feel like I am on nix system :D

Comment: loved `windosu` :)

Comment: loved the `nircmdc elevate cmd` now, is it possible not to spawn another process and get Admin privileges in the process you run the command ¿?
I have tried with `runas /user:administrador cmd.exe | sanur.exe pass` but no luck

Comment: Please don't use random executables from the web that 'help you elevate privileges'. Bad, bad practice.

Answer (score 18):

I use nirsoft programs (eg nircmdc) and sysinternals (eg psexec) all the time. They are very helpful.

But if you don't want to, or can't, dl a 3rd party program, here's another way, pure Windows.

**Short answer**: you can while elevated create a scheduled task with elevated privileges which you can then invoke later while not elevated.

**Middle-length answer**: while elevated create task with (but I prefer task scheduler GUI):

```
schtasks /create /sc once /tn cmd_elev /tr cmd /rl highest /st 00:00
```

Then later, no elevation needed, invoke with

```
schtasks /run /tn cmd_elev
```

**Long answer**: There's a lot of fidgety details; see my blog entry ["Start program WITHOUT UAC, useful at system start and in batch files (use task scheduler)"](http://montgomeryminds.com/blog/start-program-without-uac-useful-at-system-start/)

Comment: @Xalorous This solution does not use any external software

Comment: @Jeter-work `schtasks` is a built-in windows executable

Comment: I'm familiar with task scheduler, I think I must have replied to the wrong answer.

Answer (score 12):

The following as a batch file will open an elevated command prompt *with the path set to the same directory as the one from where the batch file was invoked*

```
set OLDDIR=%CD%
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/K cd %OLDDIR%' -Verb RunAs "
```

Comment: The "cd %OLDDIR%" part should be "cd /D %OLDDIR%".  Then it works also when the batch file is invoked from a drive other than the default one for cmd (usually C:).

Answer (score 7):

My favorite way of doing this is using PsExec.exe from SysInternals, available at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

```
.\psexec.exe -accepteula -h -u "$username" -p "$password" cmd.exe
```

The "-h" switch is the one doing the magic:

-h If the target system is Vista or higher, has the process run with the account's elevated token, if available.

Comment: To get this to work you must edit the properties of psexec.exe and on the compatibility tab check "Run as Administrator".  Otherwise you will get error : PSEXESVC not installed.  But psexec causes issues with the tab key in the cmd.exe.  Can't use tab to complete folder names.

Comment: Not sure on which environment you tried but I didn't need to change the "Run as Administrator" setting (are you trying to run the cmd.exe on a remote machine from yours?). Also no issues with tab key, I can successfully complete files and folders names (at least tested on Win8.1 and Win10, running from both cmd and PowerShell command lines)

Comment: I'm using Win10 and running it locally.  Not sure why it happens to me and not you.  I did get nircmd to work and it doesn't cause tab issue.

Comment: I also notice that one can't autocomplete with the tab key, but at least this would open elevated cmd prompt in context of another user, which previous methods above did not seem to achieve when I tried. The '-h' flag is great (windows 10), works a treat.

Answer (score 7):

While both solutions provided by Dheeraj Bhaskar work, unfortunately they will result in the **UAC** dialog showing up on top (z-order-wise) but **not** getting **focused** (the focused window is the caller cmd/powershell window), thus I either need to grab the mouse and click "yes", or to select the UAC window using Alt+Shift+Tab. (Tested on Win10x64 v1607 build14393.447; UAC = *"[...] do not dim [...]"*.)

The following solution is a bit awkward as it uses two files, but it preserves the correct focus order, so no extra mouse / keyboard actions are required (besides confirming the UAC dialog: *Alt+Y*).

1. cmdadm.lnk (shortcut properties / Advanced... / Run as administrator = ON)

   `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /k "cd /d"`
2. su.bat

   `@start cmdadm.lnk %cd%`

Run with `su`.

Comment: I unfortunately can't reproduce this. Whenever I use either of my solutions. My UAC prompt is focused and on top

Comment: or you could turn off UAC... Just a thought... :)

Comment: Turning of UAC is a huge security risk.

Answer (score 7):

Make the batch file save the credentials of the actual administrator account by using the `/savecred` switch.  This will prompt for credentials the first time and then store the encrypted password in credential manager.  Then for all subsequent times the batch runs it will run as the full admin but not prompt for credentials because they are stored encrypted in credential manager and the end user is unable to get the password.  The following should open an elevated CMD with full administrator privileges and will only prompt for password the first time:

```
START c:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:Administrator /savecred cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [`Elevate`](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/) for awhile now.

It's description - `This utility executes a command with UAC privilege elevation. This is useful for working inside command prompts or with batch files.`

I copy the `bin.x86-64\elevate.exe` from the `.zip` into `C:\Program Files\elevate` and add that path to my `PATH`.

Then GitBash I can run something like `elevate sc stop W3SVC` to turn off the `IIS` service.

Running the command gives me the `UAC` dialog, properly focused with keyboard control and upon accepting the dialog I return to my shell.

Comment: Please don't use random executables from the web that 'help you elevate privileges'. Bad, bad practice.

Comment: ...especially without source code.

Comment: @not2qubit It does include source code.

Comment: @gpvos Correct, it's in the .7zip and there is an .m5d hash included for verification...

Answer (score 4):

Dheeraj Bhaskar's method with Powershell has a missing space in it, alt least for the Windows 10 incarnation of Powershell.

The command line inside his sudo.bat should be

```
powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process cmd \"/k cd /d %cd% \" -Verb RunAs"
```

Note the extra space after %cd%

;)Frode

Answer (score 3):

Similar to some of the other solutions above, I created an `elevate` batch file which runs an elevated PowerShell window, bypassing the execution policy to enable running everything from simple commands to batch files to complex PowerShell scripts.  I recommend sticking it in your C:\Windows\System32 folder for ease of use.

The original `elevate` command executes its task, captures the output, closes the spawned PowerShell window and then returns, writing out the captured output to the original window.

I created two variants, `elevatep` and `elevatex`, which respectively pause and keep the PowerShell window open for more work.

https://github.com/jt-github/elevate

And in case my link ever dies, here's the code for the original elevate batch file:

```
@Echo Off
REM Executes a command in an elevated PowerShell window and captures/displays output
REM Note that any file paths must be fully qualified!

REM Example: elevate myAdminCommand -myArg1 -myArg2 someValue

if "%1"=="" (
    REM If no command is passed, simply open an elevated PowerShell window.
    PowerShell -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Wait -Verb RunAs}"
) ELSE (
    REM Copy command+arguments (passed as a parameter) into a ps1 file
    REM Start PowerShell with Elevated access (prompting UAC confirmation)
    REM     and run the ps1 file
    REM     then close elevated window when finished
    REM Output captured results

    IF EXIST %temp%\trans.txt del %temp%\trans.txt
    Echo %* ^> %temp%\trans.txt *^>^&1 > %temp%\tmp.ps1
    Echo $error[0] ^| Add-Content %temp%\trans.txt -Encoding Default >> %temp%\tmp.ps1
    PowerShell -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%temp%\tmp.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}"
    Type %temp%\trans.txt
)
```

Answer (score 3):

..

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
NET SESSION >nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 GOTO ELEVATE
GOTO :EOF

:ELEVATE
SET this="%CD%"
SET this=!this:\=\\!

MSHTA "javascript: var shell = new ActiveXObject('shell.application'); shell.ShellExecute('CMD', '/K CD /D \"!this!\"', '', 'runas', 1);close();"
EXIT 1
```

save this script as "god.cmd" in your system32 or whatever your path is directing to....

if u open a cmd in e:\mypictures\ and type god
it will ask you for credentials and put you back to that same place as the administrator...

Comment: powershell is cool but it needzz modules... im oldscool... just need the system...

Comment: Does this elevation method/trick also work for long paths/filenames? Or am i supposed to use "%~snx0" or "%~dpsnx0" instead?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to integrate with explorer.
It will popup a extra menu item when you right-click in any folder within Windows Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer Integration]

Here are the steps:

1. Create this key: `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\dosherewithadmin`
2. Change its Default value to whatever you want to appear as the menu item text.
   E.g. "*DOS Shell as Admin*"
3. Create another key: `\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\dosherewithadmin\command`
4. and change its default value to this:
   `powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs 'cmd.exe' -Args '/k pushd "%1"'"`
5. Done. Now right-click in any folder and you will see your item there within the other items.

*we use `pushd` instead of `cd` to allow it to work in any drive. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be a lot of really creative solutions on this, but I found [Stiegler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/567105/stiegler) & [Gui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3018703/gui) made the most sense to me. I was looking into how I could do this, but using it in conjunction with my domain admin credential, instead of relying on the local permissions of the "current user".

This is what I came up with:

```
runas /noprofile /user:DomainName\UserName "powershell start cmd -v runas"
```

It may seem redundant, but it does prompt for my admin password, and does come up as an elevated command prompt.

Comment: This is what I was looking for... Elevate the user itself as the admin instead of calling the Administrator. But I don't understand what's going on there... `cmd -v runas`. Why does this thing end up asking for administrative privilege?

Answer (score 2):

For fans of Cygwin:

```
cygstart -a runas cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way by far is to:

1. `CTRL+ALT+DELETE`
2. Run TASK MANAGER
3. Click `FILE > Run New Task > type in "cmd"` and tick the "Create this task with administrative privileges." box.

Not sure if this helps but this is how I managed to do it.  Doesn't help if you need a command to run from batch but hey-ho ... I needed this just because windows explorer is corrupted and needed to fix it.

This is my workaround. Hope this helps someone if not the original poster.

Comment: I never even noticed that checkbox.  Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

When a CMD script needs Administrator rights and you know it, add this line to the very top of the script (right below `@ECHO OFF`):

```
NET FILE > NUL 2>&1 || POWERSHELL -ex Unrestricted -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs -FilePath '%ComSpec%' -ArgumentList '/c \"%~fnx0\" %*'" && EXIT /b
```

The `NET FILE` checks for existing Administrator rights. If there are none, PowerShell restarts the current script (with its arguments) in an *elevated* shell, and the non-elevated script closes.

To allow running scripts [`-ex Unrestricted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy) is necessary.
[`-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe#-command) executes the following string.
[`Start-Process -Verb RunAs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process#example-5--start-powershell-as-an-administrator) runs a process **As Administrator**:
the shell (`%ComSpec%`, usually `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`) starting (`/c`) the current script ([`\"%~fnx0\"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for#:%7E:text=%7EfI)) passing its arguments ([`%*`](https://www.scribd.com/document/173382857/Using-Batch-Files#:%7E:text=%25*)).

Maybe not the exact answer to this question, but it might very well be what people need that end up here.

Comment: Can you please explain, what each of the arguments does?

Comment: @not2qubit Sure!

Answer (score 1):

A little late for an answer but answering anyway for latecomers like me.
I have two approaches. First one is based on little alteration to @Dheeraj Bhaskar's answer and second one is new(that is not mentioned in any answer here).

**Approach 1**: Create a `admin` command for windows(just for the sake of flexibility).

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -Command "Start-Process %1 -Verb RunAs"
```

Open notepad -> copy/paste above script -> save it as admin.bat in c:\windows

A lot can be added in the above script to make it better but I've tried to keep it simple and also because I'm not an expert in batch scripting.

Now you can use *admin* as command to run any other command or application with **elevated privileges**.

To answer the original question- type `admin cmd` in standard cmd.

**Approach 2**:Using ***runas*** command. For this we need to enable the **built-in Administrator account** if not already enabled and set a password. This account is disabled by default on most systems.

> When manufacturing PCs, you can use the built-in Administrator account to run programs and apps before a user account is created. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-and-disable-the-built-in-administrator-account?view=windows-10)

Steps to enable Administrator account-

1. Hit Windows+R and type `compmgmt.msc` which will open Computer Management window.
2. Go to System Tools -> Local Users and Groups -> Users
3. You should see an account with name Administrator here(more info about this account can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-and-disable-the-built-in-administrator-account?view=windows-10)).
4. Right click on Administrator and select Properties.
5. Check Password never expires. Uncheck Account is Disabled and everything else then click OK. This will enable administrator account on your system. Skip if already enabled.
6. Again Right click on Administrator and click on Set Password(by default it has no password set but for `runas` command to work we need to set a password).
   Now windows will show you a life threatening warning which you can accept.
   OR If you want to play safe then you should login into it after enabling this account and set a password from there.

Now `runas` command should work-
Start a standard cmd and type-

`runas /user:administrator cmd`

**EXTRA**:
Now we can create something similar to Linux's `sudo` command. Create a **sudo.bat** file with following script and save it in c:\windows.

```
@ECHO OFF
powershell -Command "runas /user:administrator %1"
```

Now we can do `sudo cmd`

Answer (score 1):

I did this for my smartctl, and it became a portable App.
I borrowed it from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024426/16936169)

```
@echo off

set location=%cd%\bin
powershell -Command "Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList { '/k "TITLE Smartctl" & color 07 & pushd "%location%" & prompt $g & echo "Welcome to Smartctl cmd"' }"
```

`prompt $g` hides the long leading path.
`pushd "%location%"` is similar to `cd /d "%location%"`

1. Saved as `smartctl.cmd`
2. Create a shortcut for `smartctl.cmd`
3. Copy the shortcut to `C:\Users\#YourName#\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs`
4. Click search next to the start menu and input `smartctl`
5. Right click `Pin to Start`

Answer (score 1):

Install [gsudo](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo) tool and use `gsudo` command. UAC popup appears and eventually command prompt right in the current console window will be elevated:

```
C:\Users\Someone>net session
System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.

C:\Users\Someone>gsudo
C:\Users\Someone# net session
There are no entries in the list.
```

The tool can be installed using [various package managers](https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo#installation) (Scoop, WinGet, Chocolatey).

Comment: `gsudo` is a great tool! I want to add that it can also be called via just `sudo` (which is a shortcut to the actual `gsudo.exe`). I.e. you can omit the 'g' at the start.

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks. Would you know how to get the hash prompt for an elevated shell?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the command:
runas /noprofile /user:administrator cmd

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`start`, `run`, `cmd`, then `control+shift+enter`

You'll get UAC and then an elevated command shell.

Answer (score 0):

Create text file named "admin_cmd.reg" with the following content, and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
@="Cmd here as admin"
"HasLUAShield"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-5324"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /s /k pushd \"%V\""
```

Click on empty space in any folder will give you "**Cmd here as admin**"

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Can use a temporary environment variable to use with an elevated shortcut (

start.cmd

```
setx valueName_betterSpecificForEachCase %~dp0
"%~dp0ascladm.lnk"
```

ascladm.lnk (shortcut)

```
_ properties\advanced\"run as administrator"=yes
```

(to make path changes you'll need to temporarily create the `env.Variable`)

```
_ properties\target="%valueName_betterSpecificForEachCase%\ascladm.cmd"

_ properties\"start in"="%valueName_betterSpecificForEachCase%"
```

ascladm.cmd

```
setx valueName_betterSpecificForEachCase=
reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment /F /V valueName_betterSpecificForEachCase
"%~dp0fileName_targetedCmd.cmd"
```

) (targetedCmd gets executed in elevated cmd window)

Although it is 3 files ,you can place everything (including targetedCmd) in some subfolder (do not forget to add the folderName to the patches) and rename "start.cmd" to targeted's one name

For me it looks like most native way of doing this ,whilst cmd doesn't have the needed command

Comment: i have read all of above solutions and understood them. i do not understand steps of yours. i am choosing solution with best pros and cons.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following syntax, I had the same question and did not think a script should be needed.

> runas /profile /user:domain\username cmd

This worked for me, it may be different on your network.

Answer (score -2):

I did it easily by using this following command in **cmd**

**runas /netonly /user:Administrator\Administrator cmd**

after typing this command, you have to enter your Administrator password(if you don't know your Administrator password leave it blank and press **Enter** or type something, worked for me)..

Comment: did not help me

Comment: @DzmitryLahoda can you brief me the error that you got?

Answer (score -2):

Press the Windows + X key and you can now select the Powershell or  Command Prompt with admin rights. Works if you are the admin. The function can be unusable if the system is not yours.

Answer (score -3):

I've created this tool in .Net 4.8 [**ExecElevated.exe, 13KB**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19w3G6pADTUs5E5NSk437m0o_GYfJUgNe/view?usp=sharing) ([VS 2022 source project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16w7uIqeAYVcCYYk5AVXYQA0H-jNLVH3B/view?usp=sharing)) it will execute an application with an elevated token (in admin mode).
But you will get an UAC dialog to confirm! (maybe not if UAC has been disabled, haven't tested it).

And the account calling the tool must also have admin. rights of course.

Example of use:

```
ExecuteElevated.exe "C:\Utility\regjump.exe HKCU\Software\Classes\.pdf"
```

Comment: I just love the answers with "This might work haven't tested yet", and of course the one with "not sure"....

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Link reestablished, sorry for that

Comment: Please don't use random executables from the web that 'help you elevate privileges'.  Bad, bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, at least post the source code to these things.

Comment: I made it many years ago and not for the purpose of this thread and I don't have the source anymore (sorry). And I do agree with all of you, you shouldn't use binaries from unknowns.  But it's your choice, no one force you to use it. If you don't like it, then don't use it.

Comment: Found the old project, link updated. Require .Net  Framework 4.8

Answer (score -5):

I used `runas /user:domainuser@domain cmd` which opened an elevated prompt successfully.

Comment: It requires the credentials of another user. If you're already Administrator and want to run with elevated privileges like when you right click an application and choose run as administrator and no password is requested, just a confirmation dialog, then you need something else. I came here searching for that answer but doesn't seem to be here.

Answer (score -6):

There are several ways to open an elevated cmd, but only your method works from the standard command prompt. You just need to put `user` not `username`:

```
runas /user:machinename\adminuser cmd
```

See relevant help from [Microsoft community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/command-to-elevate-a-command-prompt-to-an/e8900dae-73e4-4232-a549-c0010f9e592f).

Comment: This is not the same thing as running an elevated command, because when I open an elevated cmd window and I type "whoami" it brings the same result as a non elevated window. When I run "whoami /all" in both cases I can see the differences in terms of permissions for the very same user.