# How can i run cmd as administrator privileges by cmd command without using any shortcut of cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, administrator

I am trying to open Command Prompt as Administrator Privileges by using command line...Is it possible to make a open cmd to a Administrator privileged cmd??

Thanks

Comment: You can make a shortcut that has the *run as administrator* compatibility option checked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open an elevated cmd using command line for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098101/open-an-elevated-cmd-using-command-line-for-windows)

Comment: The accepted answer works, not you can use the answer below to run an elevated command prompt window that will run everything as admin as such: `runas /profile /user:AdminName cmd.exe` type `net user` in cmd to get a list of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a DOS command you can use to run as administrator in command line:

```
runas /profile /user:administrator “Driver:\folder\program”
```

For example, the administrator account is `“AAA”` and you want to run `BBB.exe` of `C:\programs`, you should do these

1. Press Win key & R
2. Input “CMD” in open box and click “OK”
3. Input: `runas /profile /user:AAA “C:\programs\BBB.exe”`  and press “Enter”
4. Input the password of administrator AAA
5. Press “Enter”

found via a simple google search

Comment: sorry done via my phone not pc so formatting is up the creek

Comment: That's surely not what is desired. The asker likely doesn't want to run as a different user. Asker wants to elevate new process as current user.

Comment: Perhaps that's what you meant to write in your answer