# How do I start cmd.exe /k with multiple commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Why doesn't the following code change the color and the title on **cmd2**? How, and what to do? The command changes color on **cmd1**, and sets the title on **cmd2**?

```
start cmd.exe /k TITLE TEST & color 02 & mode con: cols=160 lines=78
```

Comment: 1. you intend to open a new `cmd` window, right? (because of `start`) 2. the `mode` command is missing at the last part...

Comment: Right. Corrected for future reference, and thanks.

Answer (score 20):

```
start "TEST" cmd.exe /k "TITLE TEST & color 02 & mode con: cols=160 lines=78"
```

Without quoting the command that the new `cmd` instance must execute, the `&` is interpreted as a command concatenation after the `start` and so it is executed in the first instance. With quotes, it is part of the command to execute in the second `cmd` instance.

Also, as the `start` command sees the first quoted argument as the tile of the window to start, and we are going to use quotes, it is necessary to include a title in the command (or `""` for no title).

Comment: Thanks a lot it was driving me crazy :)

Comment: is there a way to do this with a multiline command ?