# Start cmd, run exe and after the program ends run command pause and then exit

Tags: windows, cmd, command

How can I open a new command promt and run in there an exe and after the program (exe) ends run command `pause` and then `exit`

Exe is running by:

```
start cmd /k bla.exe
```

After bla.exe is done, I want to run a pause command. I tried:

```
start cmd /k bla.exe & pause
```

but pause is running in the initial console.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I start cmd.exe /k with multiple commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024344/how-do-i-start-cmd-exe-k-with-multiple-commands)

Comment: I read it know, but it does not help

Comment: The accepted answer pretty clearly says that you need to enquote the commands you want to execute. You didn’t do that, so I have to assume that you didn’t read the answer correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
start "titel" cmd /k "bla.exe & pause & exit"
```