# PhpStorm - run terminal (cmd) as administrator

Tags: cmd, terminal, phpstorm, administrator

On Windows it's easy to run `cmd` application as administrator:

```
Right click on cmd icon >> run as administrator`
```

But I would like to use `PhpStorm terminal` tool as administrator since I constantly have to execute queries that require administrator role.

When I open:

```
File >> Settings >> Tools >> Terminal
```

I can see that it is directly connected to `cmd.exe` and there are options to be filled:

[image]

And I see no checkbox with choice to run it as administrator.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is it even possible?
2. If yes how do I do it?
3. Using settings or other way?

Comment: Would this not be covered by running PhpStorm itself as an administrator?

Comment: Wow that was the solution. Didn't even pop to my head. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work for me using webstorm 2016.2 Terminal appears not to be started with admin rights although webstorm was. Have to use a bog-standard windows terminal with admin rights to issue 'ionic serve'

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are no options in the IDE for running the shell (`cmd.exe`,  `powershell.exe` etc.) with higher rights at the moment.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-121335 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. Maybe someone will post some possible workarounds there...

---

**Your only option for now (that I'm aware of)** is running the IDE itself as Administrator. I have tried this myself and the Process Hacker tool confirms that both the IDE and `cmd.exe` will be run with elevated rights.

---

**P.S.**
For one time execution (or if you need to run the IDE as normal user): have a look at this question and offered solutions: [How to open an elevated cmd using command line for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098101/783119)