# Running Windows container's command prompt in admin mode

Tags: windows, docker, containers, windows-server

I am running Windows Nanoserver in a container.The nanoserver contains only the command prompt and lacks powershell.

I want to execute certain commands inside the container in the command prompt which require elevated privileges. I am currently using the following to launch the command prompt of the container.

`docker exec -it <container_id> cmd`

Is there any other way using which we can run the command prompt in admin mode?

Comment: There are a bunch of different options here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098101/how-to-open-an-elevated-cmd-using-command-line-for-windows

Comment: These solutions don't work with Windows Nanoserver. It contains only the command prompt with fewer packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Windows documentation, the Windows Server Core has `ContainerAdministrator` as the default user whereas Windows NanoServer has `ContainerUser` as the default user.

I was able to connect to my container as admin using the following command-

`docker exec --user ContainerAdministrator -it <container_id> cmd`

Answer (score -2):

Run the cmd from C:\Windows\System
docker run -it <image_name>: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe