# Python/Django run development server

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-1.8, manage.py

I'm trying to create a project using Django 1.8.4 and Python 2.7.10, but I can't execute the command `python manage.py runserver`. I can create the project and apps, but can't run the server.
Please somebody help me, I'm new with Python/Django and I couldn't advance more.
The cmd show the next error when the command is executed.

> C:\Users\Efren\SkyDrive\UniCosta\VIII\Ingeniería de Software
>   II\Django\PrimerProyecto>python manage.py runserver Performing system
>   checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced). Unhandled exception in
>   thread started by  Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 225, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 112, in inner_run
>       self.check_migrations()
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 164, in check_migrations
>       executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line
>   19, in **init**
>       self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py",
>   line 47, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py",
>   line 182, in build_graph
>       self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line
>   59, in applied_migrations
>       self.ensure_schema()
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line
>   49, in ensure_schema
>       if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line
>   162, in cursor
>       cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line
>   135, in _cursor
>       self.ensure_connection()
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line
>   130, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 97, in
>   **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line
>   130, in ensure_connection
>       self.connect()
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line
>   119, in connect
>       self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
>
> File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py",
>   line 204, in get_new_connection
>       conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
>
> django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate` to get the database up and running?

Comment: how is your database name on settings?

Comment: Please share the database settings in settings.py.

Comment: @knbk I'm run the command and gets an error                                           File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)  ...

Comment: @PauloPessoa                                                                                      DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

Comment: @RajkumarRajendran DATABASES = { 'default': { 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'), }

Comment: Please locate the `db.sqlite3` file and check its permissions and ownership. Ideally It should be present in your project base directory according to your setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems pretty clear that Django is unable to find your database at specified location, reasons can be,

1. You have created django project using "sudo" or with any other other linux user than your current user, thats why your current user might not have permissions to access that database. You can check permissions of files by typing in your project's root directory,

   ls -la
2. You have configured wrong path for database file in your settings.py

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you are looking for is the following:

```
sudo python manage.py runserver
```

I was struggling with the same issue and this has finally done the trick for me.
**superuser do**  to the rescue!

**edit:**  If you are on windows and want to test this solution out then this link has some options:
[How to run 'sudo' command in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652720/how-to-run-sudo-command-in-windows)

Comment: That seems unlikely in this case since the user appears to be on Windows :)