# Python anaconda access denied

Tags: python, windows, command-line, tensorflow, installation

I'm trying to update tensorflow.

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

It first checks for the packages and creates the following error

```
Installing collected packages: markdown, werkzeug, numpy, tensorflow-gpu, setuptools
Found existing installation: Markdown 2.2.0
Uninstalling Markdown-2.2.0:    
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\markdown-2.2.0.dist-info\\description.rst'
```

I'm not very experienced with Windows, I did all my work on Linux so far, so what do I do here?

Comment: Have you tried `runas`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652720/how-to-run-sudo-command-in-windows

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you choose to install Anaconda for All Users you will need to escalate privileges on the Command Prompt. Right click CMD and choose "Run As Admin". If you do not want to do this every time you will need to set the permissions on the entire Anaconda directory for you user to Full Access.

Comment: With the recent release of Windows10, this now sits under the 'more' menu.

Answer (score 4):

Run the cmd in administrative mode and type

pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu --user

This worked for me