# Sudo on windows

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, permissions, admin

Hey I ran into the error of BSOD 0xc000021a and I already found some solutions using the „emergency commandline“ at X:/Windows when running into recovery Options.

Sadly it is constantly disallowing me to use Commands Bc of Not enough permissions. I know the Password and got a Windows shell but not the option to Right click for executing as admin.

Any help is deeply needed. Thank you in advance!

Comment: or see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652720/how-to-run-sudo-command-in-windows#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20sudo%20command,choosing%20%22run%20as%20administrator.%22&text=Then%2C%20save%20the%20file%20as%20sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no sudo command in Windows. The nearest equivalent is "run as administrator." 
You can do this using the runas command with an administrator trust-level, or by right-clicking the program in the UI and choosing "run as administrator."

Comment: It's coming - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-sudo-for-windows/