# unable run any command inside virtual environment python

Tags: python, virtual-environment

i have create a virtual environment , have activated it but inside that not commands pip or python as such is not working.

Output:

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There is no native `sudo` in Windows. [see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652749/4225384 ]  Open PowerShell as Administrator, then you can input commands without sudo (i.e. just `pip install flask`).

Comment: Alternatively, install packages for you only by `pip install --user ...`. This doesn't require administrator privileges since it installs into your user home.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native `sudo` command in Windows, so run the following command in your Visual Studio Code terminal to install flask.

```
pip3 install flask
```

According to the screenshot in your question your installed Python version is Python 3.10 (currently the latest Python version) which is located at `C:\Users\Hp Lap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe`.

It is possible to run Python, C, C++, JavaScript, PHP, Java, R and some other programming language code blocks directly in Visual Studio Code using the Code Runner extension. The Extensions pane is used for installing extensions in Visual Studio Code. It is accessed by clicking the Extensions icon which looks four square blocks in the vertical pane at the left side of Visual Studio Code.