# How to give users the right to use typeperf.exe

Tags: windows, permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to run the following command `typeperf -sc 1 "processor(_Total)\% Processor Time"`

To retreive the cpu load in percentage

The command work well when i run it though my username since I am the adminstrator.

I created an other user called `test`

logged in with test and tried to run the command with the `test` user and getting

```
Exiting, please wait...                         
Error: No valid counters.
```

I correctly added the `test` user in the `Performance Log Users` group as the typeperf.exe application is supposed to only let those user use it

Please also note that this question is in some way related to [Not enough permission to run typeperf.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379302/not-enough-permision-to-run-typeperf-exe) question I asked a few days ago.

I am wondering what can I do more to let an other user use typeperf.exe

I am using Windows 8 Pro in case this information is relevant

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Edit----------------

As asked in comment

When I run the folowing command `typeperf -q Processor` on the `test` user i get the following response

```
\Processor(*)\% Processor Time
\Processor(*)\% User Time
\Processor(*)\% Privileged Time
\Processor(*)\Interrupts/sec
\Processor(*)\% DPC Time
\Processor(*)\% Interrupt Time
\Processor(*)\DPCs Queued/sec
\Processor(*)\DPC Rate
\Processor(*)\% Idle Time
\Processor(*)\% C1 Time
\Processor(*)\% C2 Time
\Processor(*)\% C3 Time
\Processor(*)\C1 Transitions/sec
\Processor(*)\C2 Transitions/sec
\Processor(*)\C3 Transitions/sec
Exiting, please wait...                         
The command completed successfully.
```

Comment: Works fine for me (Windows 7 SP1) without being an admin or in the `Performance Log Users` group.  What does `typeperf -q Processor` say?

Comment: Thanks for your input,  I added the response of the command in my OP

Answer (score 1):

You just got to escape % symbol, e.g.: typeperf "\Process(Idle)\%% Processor Time"

Comment: Yes, if it's invoked from the batch file. It wasn't about user rights after all.

Comment: The OP didn't mention using a batch file - but it's an entirely reasonable guess, and one that hadn't occurred to me.  +1.