# How to open Ms-Word document as administrator by default?

Tags: c#, ms-word

How to open Ms-Word document as administrator by default?

I want to open word document as administrator by default , Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use batch file. It is script for this in thread below:

[How do you run a command as an administrator from the Windows shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944180/how-do-you-run-a-command-as-an-administrator-from-the-windows-shell)

Remember to change "cmd.exe" in script to path to application You want to run.

Kind regards,
A.