# customization command-line based installer

Tags: python, automation, installation, uac

I want to use python to create an application for installing multiple programs. Most of witch have unique command line switches to make them install silently. I only want UAC to pop up once.

A year ago I created one but it is not easily customization. Meaning if I want to add a new program to the install list I have to open the code and added it manually.

> The main thing I need answered is how to have UAC prompt once.

Comment: "if I want to add a new program to the install list I have to open the code..." So, you already have a script that does this? Why not read in the list of executables to install from an external file, then?

Comment: I am looking for a gui that will allow me to easily add them. However most importantly I want to get away form building a batch file to run the installs and just use os.system(). However if I use os.system() I end up with each application prompting UAC request.

Comment: Not entirely certain, but if you have a Py script to install the executables, and you run it with elevated privileges, you might not see the dialog more than once. I asked a related question a while back, and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5969764/712526) may help you.

Comment: (Note that I never tried it, as I had "moved on" by the time it was posted.)

Comment: ah yes I read this one. it is similar to how my current program works. I use pyinstaller to create stand alone applications. The force UAC switch has never worked properly for me.

Comment: You would do this by provoking elevation for your program that wants to install other things. Once it elevates, you can install the other programs without the prompt (seeing as you are already elevated).