# .bat file running cmd with specific command lines

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a batch file that will open cmd.exe (as an administrator) with these lines:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Putty

cd C:\Program Files\Putty>psftp -i XXXXXXXXX.ppk xxxx_test@111.111.111.11 -b C:\UPLOAD\upload.ftp
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you starting this - from an explorer shortcut? There should be a 'run as administator' flag you can check. Or from a command line there's e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5944180/243245)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run a command as an administrator from the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944180/how-do-you-run-a-command-as-an-administrator-from-the-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

## DoStuff.bat

```
@echo off
runas /user:%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME% "cmd.exe /K \"cd C:\Program Files\Putty\" & psftp -i XXXXXXXXX.ppk xxxx_test@111.111.111.11 -b C:\UPLOAD\upload.ftp"
```

- `runas` will let you run a command as Administrator (you may need to change the domain/user to match your system, and enter a password).
- Running `cmd.exe /K` will run the following commands.
- The quotes around the commands need to be escaped with `\"`

I'm having a hard time seeing the difficulty.
Can you explain what you tried, and why it didn't work?