# permission denied when install new version of gcc in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to install new version of gcc in cygwin. I follow this link. http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/

After I downloaded and installed cygwin64, I moved the setup-x86_64.exe from my download folder to cygwin64 folder, which is located in my C drive. Then I cd to cygwin64 directory and used the command shown in the step 2

```
$ C:\cygwin64>setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel
```

But it said the following

```
-bash: setup-x86_64.exe: Permission denied
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried: 1) Running Cygwin in admin mode from Windows? 2) Using `sudo su` inside Cygwin?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I try to follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090301/root-user-sudo-equivalent-in-cygwin. But when I type "cygstart --action=runas command" but it said "Unable to start 'command" but it return "The specified file was not found". So I wonder what directory should I be in?

Comment: Wait...did you first try right clicking the Cygwin icon and running it as Administrstor?

Comment: questions: can you run setup-x86_64.exe from windows ? What are the permission visable from cygwin `ls -l setup-x86_64.exe` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It works with the right click. Thanks.