# Can't install gatsby-source-tumblr

Tags: node.js, npm, tumblr, gatsby

I found the gatsby-source-tumblr at www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-tumblr/ and decided to give it a go since I have pictures on tumblr that I would like to show on my gatsby site.

However, it won't install.

Here's the error:

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\christoffer.rydestah\Documents\Repos\napoli-cafe\node_modules\.bin\json5.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\christoffer.rydestah\Documents\Repos\napoli-cafe\node_modules\.bin\json5.cmd: ..\@babel\core\node_modules\json5\lib\cli.js symlink target is not controlled by npm C:\Users\christoffer.rydestah\Documents\Repos\napoli-cafe\node_modules\json5
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\christoffer.rydestah\Documents\Repos\napoli-cafe\node_modules\.bin\json5.cmdnpm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm ERR!     C:\Users\christoffer.rydestah\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-31T08_56_28_688Z-debug.logC:\Users\christoffer.rydestah\Documents\Repos\napoli-cafe>sudo npm install --save gatsby-source-tumblr
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Has anyone experienced this problem with this plugin? 
Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: delete your node_modules and run `npm i`  check again and don't run anything with sudo

Comment: @Pardeep this problem is occur from `window`.

Comment: I just see 'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command :P

Comment: @KingStone is right, it's a window problem. Tried to install the plugin on my macbook and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install something like [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) for run bash scripts.
But cygwin does not have sudo command as well, and in this case you can create some stub script for this command [cydwyn sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090301/root-user-sudo-equivalent-in-cygwin)

Comment: I installed cygwin, but it still doesn't work. Anyway, I installed the plugin on my macbook and it worked. Thanks for your time!